# JSPM / System.js debugging with TypeScript

Tags: systemjs, jspm

when debugging JSPM / System.js with TypeScript often the break point will stop at the wrong place... using sourcemap and still same issue.

Any solution? anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @develar from JetBrains, using WebStorm you can now enable the fix for JSPM source maps.

in websorm do Help -> Find Action -> Registry
next find js.debugger.fix.jspm.source.maps and check
and turn on

[image]

you need the latest WebStorm, right now fix is in beta .145 branch,

hope it helps others,

regards,

Sean.